# Use a single pod in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

In my project I've around 20-30 PODS and all of them are in `OBJECTIVE-C`.
In some of the pods I've changed some pieces of code due to requirement.
Now I want to add a pod which is only written in swift. Is it possible to use swift for only that specific pod ? I don't want to use "use_framework" as it will force all other pods to use static frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently use_framework! is either all or none. There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3839) to change that.

[Swift static library](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6966) support will be added in CocoaPods 1.5.0 so that is likely to be the soonest route to a solution for you, but still a ways off.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of cocoapods 1.5.0. Not it's possible to use only a single swift pods. From official docs

```
you can add use_modular_headers! to enable the stricter search paths and
module map generation for all of your pods, 
or you can add :modular_headers => true to a single pod declaration
to enable for only that pod.
```

By this we can improve store submission time. Here is the official doc page [Cocoapods 1.5.0](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/).